# Postgres 12 - createdb: error: database creation failed: ERROR: database "postgres" already exists

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a database through "createdb" in postgres 12 and using below command,

```
/pgsql-12/bin/createdb --host localhost --port XXXX --username postgres --owner ZZZZZ --encoding 'UTF8' --lc-collate 'en_IN.utf8' --lc-ctype 'en_IN.utf8' --tablespace pg_default --template template0 mytestdb
```

It works successfully when i execute from command line (-bash-4.2$) but when i put the same command in shell script as below,

```
#!/bin/sh
dbs_arr=(mytestdb)

for i in ${dbs_arr[@]}
    do
        echo database $i - start at $(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S")  
        PGPASSWORD="$password" /pgsql-12/bin/createdb --host localhost --port XXXX --username postgres --owner ZZZZZ --encoding 'UTF8' --lc-collate 'en_IN.utf8' --lc-ctype 'en_IN.utf8' --tablespace pg_default --template template0 $i    
        echo database $i - end at $(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S")  
    done
```

It throws error,

**createdb: error: database creation failed: ERROR:  database "postgres" already exists**

please suggest something to  fix this.

Comment: Must be a bug in your application, and `i` is not set. Replace `$i` with `"$i"` and observe how the error changes.

Comment: when i put "$i", got error - createdb: error: database creation failed: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: CREATE DATABASE "" OWNER ZZZZ TABLESPACE pg_default ENCODIN...

Comment: See? `i` is empty. A bug in your shell script.